# Event being triggered without any declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, ext.net

First of all, let me present to you the exception I get in the screen.

```
The control 'Store1' does not have an DirectEvent with the name 'DataChanged' or the handler is absent
```

I have some pages in my project, when I go under the page "A" and change to the page "B" and then hit backspace ( so I go to the last page I was ), I get that error. But if I go to the page "B" and change back to "A", I get no error.

I noticed that when the error occurs, a column I added is not there, and since the bind to the ext.Store happens when the page is not postback, I can't watch the value that has been through.

Now, this is the grid that holds the ext.Store :

```
<ext:GridPanel id="GridPanel1" idmode="Explicit" runat="server" autoheight="true"
        title="Solicitações" autoexpandcolumn="Descricao">
        <Store>
            <ext:Store ID="Store1" runat="server" GroupField="solCodigo" GroupOnSort="true">
                <Reader>
                    <ext:JsonReader IDProperty="solCodigo">
                        <Fields>
                            <ext:RecordField Name="solCodigo" SortDir="DESC" />
                            <ext:RecordField Name="solDescricao" Type="String" />
                            <ext:RecordField Name="solStatus" Type="String" />
                            <ext:RecordField Name="proDescricao" Type="String" />
                            <ext:RecordField Name="solDataSolicitacao" Type="Date" />
                            <ext:RecordField Name="solDataPrevista" Type="Date" />
                            <ext:RecordField Name="solNumArquivos" />
                            <ext:RecordField Name="funNomeSolucionador" Type="String" />
                            <ext:RecordField Name="solPrioridade" />
                            <ext:RecordField Name="solDataSolucao" Type="String" />
                        </Fields>
                    </ext:JsonReader>
                </Reader>
            </ext:Store>
        </Store>
        <View>
            <%--
            <ext:GroupingView runat="server" HideGroupedColumn="true" EmptyGroupText="Indefinido" ID="groupingView1" EnableGrouping="false" EnableGroupingMenu="false">
                <GetRowClass Fn="getRowClass" />
            </ext:GroupingView>--%>
        </View>
        <ColumnModel runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <ext:Column DataIndex="solCodigo" Header="Código" Width="40">
                </ext:Column>
                <ext:Column ColumnID="Descricao" Header="Descrição" DataIndex="solDescricao">
                    <Renderer Format="Ellipsis" FormatArgs="50" />
                    <Commands>
                        <ext:ImageCommand CommandName="Comando" />
                    </Commands>
                    <PrepareCommand Fn="prepareCellCommand" />
                </ext:Column>
                <ext:DateColumn Header="Solicitado em" DataIndex="solDataSolicitacao">
                </ext:DateColumn>
                <ext:DateColumn Header="Data prevista" DataIndex="solDataPrevista">
                </ext:DateColumn>
                <ext:Column ColumnID="Projeto" Header="Projeto" DataIndex="proDescricao">
                </ext:Column>
                <ext:Column Header="Situação" DataIndex="solStatus">
                    <Renderer Fn="situacaoRender" />
                </ext:Column>
                <ext:Column Header="Data de Solução" DataIndex="solDataSolucao">
                </ext:Column>
                <ext:Column Header="Prioridade" DataIndex="solPrioridade">
                    <Renderer Fn="prioridadeRender" />
                </ext:Column>
            </Columns>
        </ColumnModel>
        <DirectEvents>
            <DblClick OnEvent="GridPanel1_DblClick" Before="if(#{GridPanel1}.getSelectionModel().getSelected() == undefined) return false; ">
                <EventMask ShowMask="true" />
                <ExtraParams>
                    <%-- or can use params[2].id as value --%>
                    <%-- <ext:Parameter Name="id" Value="#{GridPanel1}.getSelectionModel().getSelected().id;"
                        Mode="Raw" />--%>
                    <ext:Parameter Name="Values" Value="Ext.encode(#{GridPanel1}.getRowsValues({selectedOnly:true}))"
                        Mode="Raw" />
                </ExtraParams>
            </DblClick>
        </DirectEvents>
        <Plugins>
            <%--  <ext:RowExpander ID="RowExpander1" runat="server" >
                <Template ID="Template1" runat="server">
                    <Html>
                        <p><b>Detalhes:</b> {solDescricao}</p>
                        <p><b>Arquivos:</b> {solNumArquivos}</p>
                    </Html>
                </Template>
            </ext:RowExpander>--%>
        </Plugins>
        <SelectionModel>
            <ext:RowSelectionModel runat="server" SingleSelect="true" />
        </SelectionModel>
    </ext:GridPanel>
```

And how it bound

```
 DataTable dtSol = new DataTable();
                dtSol = sol.Listar();
                DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
                dtResult.Columns.Add("solCodigo", typeof(int));
                dtResult.Columns.Add("solDescricao", typeof(string));
                dtResult.Columns.Add("solDataSolicitacao", typeof(DateTime));
                dtResult.Columns.Add("solDataPrevista", typeof(DateTime));
                dtResult.Columns.Add("proDescricao", typeof(string));
                dtResult.Columns.Add("solStatus", typeof(string));
                dtResult.Columns.Add("solPrioridade", typeof(int));
                dtResult.Columns.Add("solDataSolucao", typeof(string));

                var result = from r in dtSol.AsEnumerable()
                             select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[] 
                             {
                                 r.Field<int>("solCodigo"),
                                 r.Field<string>("solDescricao"),
                                 r.Field<DateTime>("solDataSolicitacao"),
                                 r.Field<DateTime>("solDataPrevista"),
                                 r.Field<string>("proDescricao"),
                                 r.Field<string>("solStatus"),
                                 r.Field<int>("solPrioridade"),
                                 r.Field<DateTime>("solDataSolucao") > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1) ? string.Empty : r.Field<DateTime>("solDataSolucao").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                             }, false);

                this.Store1.DataSource = result.ToList().Any() ? dtResult : new DataTable();

                this.Store1.DataBind();
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** User Request

```
protected void GridPanel1_DblClick(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
        {
            //string ID = e.ExtraParams["id"];
            string json = e.ExtraParams["Values"];

            json = json.Replace("solNumArquivos\":\"\"", "solNumArquivos\":0");

            clSolicitacao sol = JSON.Deserialize<List<clSolicitacao>>(json).First();
            if (sol.solStatus == "DF")
            {
                Response.Redirect("Chamado.aspx?codigo=" + sol.solCodigo);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("ExibirChamado.aspx?codigo=" + sol.solCodigo);
            }


        }
```

**EDIT 2**

```
Ext.onReady(function(){Ext.QuickTips.init();Ext.apply(Ext.net.DirectMethods, { EfetuaLogout:function(blnLogout,config){Ext.net.DirectMethod.request("EfetuaLogout",Ext.applyIf(config || {}, {params:{blnLogout:blnLogout}}));} });new Ext.net.LinkButton({id:"menuBuscar",labelAlign:"top",renderTo:"menuBuscar_Container",width:50,arrowAlign:"bottom",iconAlign:"top",iconCls:"icon-magnifier",menu:{id:"ctl00",xtype:"menu",width:140,items:[{id:"ctl01",xtype:"menutextitem",text:"Código:"},{id:"txtBusca",xtype:"textfield",autoCreate:{"tag":"input","type":"text","maxlength":7,"autocomplete":"off"},maxLength:7,directEvents:{specialkey:{fn:function(el,e){var params=arguments;Ext.net.DirectEvent.confirmRequest({formProxyArg:"Form1",eventMask:{showMask:true,msg:"Buscando solicitações..."},before:function(el, type, action, extraParams){return e.getKey() == Ext.EventObject.ENTER;},control:this,action:'SpecialKey'});},delay:20}}},{id:"ctl02",iconCls:"icon-magnifier",text:"Buscar",directEvents:{click:{fn:function(el,e){var params=arguments;Ext.net.DirectEvent.confirmRequest({formProxyArg:"Form1",eventMask:{showMask:true,msg:"Buscando solicitações..."},control:this});},delay:20}}}]},text:"Buscar solicitação"});new Ext.net.GridPanel({store:this.Store1=new Ext.ux.data.PagingStore({proxyId:"Store1",autoLoad:true,reader:new Ext.data.JsonReader({fields:[{name:"solCodigo",sortDir:"DESC"},{name:"solDescricao",type:"string"},{name:"solStatus",type:"string"},{name:"proDescricao",type:"string"},{name:"solDataSolicitacao",type:"date",dateFormat:"Y-m-dTh:i:s"},{name:"solDataPrevista",type:"date",dateFormat:"Y-m-dTh:i:s"},{name:"solNumArquivos"},{name:"funNomeSolucionador",type:"string"},{name:"solPrioridade"}],idProperty:"solCodigo"}),directEventConfig:{formProxyArg:"Form1"},groupField:"solCodigo",groupOnSort:true,proxy:new Ext.data.PagingMemoryProxy([{"solCodigo":2213,"solDataSolicitacao":"2013-04-16T11:16:23","solDataPrevista":"2013-04-17T11:16:23","solPrioridade":3,"solDescricao":"Gostaria de ter acesso a base dbCOEServiceDesk do servidor BRSPTP09.\r\n\r\nO motivo do pedido &#233; para poder aplicar testes e implementar o pr&#243;prio sistema do ServiceDesk assim como foi relatado nas pend&#234;ncias relatadas pelo Silva, Paulo Roberto da.\r\n\r\nO usu&#225;rio para qual o acesso &#233; solicitado &#233; &quot; aseixas &quot;. O mesmo do solicitante deste chamado.\r\n\r\nGrato.","solStatus":"SP","proDescricao":"CrCt(Petrobrás) - SP","funNomeSolucionador":"DANIELA BRITO COSTA                               ","solNumArquivos":0},{"solCodigo":2214,"solDataSolicitacao":"2013-05-10T15:33:11","solDataPrevista":"2013-05-11T15:33:11","solPrioridade":3,"solDescricao":"sdfgdf","solStatus":"SF","proDescricao":"Consiste","funNomeSolucionador":"ANDRE SILVA DE SEIXAS                             ","solNumArquivos":0},{"solCodigo":2215,"solDataSolicitacao":"2013-05-13T13:43:34","solDataPrevista":"2013-05-14T13:43:34","solPrioridade":3,"solDescricao":"abc","solStatus":"SP","proDescricao":null,"funNomeSolucionador":null,"solNumArquivos":0},{"solCodigo":2216,"solDataSolicitacao":"2013-05-13T13:45:06","solDataPrevista":"2013-05-14T13:45:06","solPrioridade":3,"solDescricao":"abc","solStatus":"SP","proDescricao":null,"funNomeSolucionador":null,"solNumArquivos":0},{"solCodigo":2217,"solDataSolicitacao":"2013-05-13T13:47:01","solDataPrevista":"2013-05-14T13:47:01","solPrioridade":3,"solDescricao":"abc","solStatus":"SP","proDescricao":null,"funNomeSolucionador":null,"solNumArquivos":0},{"solCodigo":2218,"solDataSolicitacao":"2013-05-13T13:52:43","solDataPrevista":"2013-05-14T13:52:43","solPrioridade":3,"solDescricao":"asdf","solStatus":"SP","proDescricao":"Connector","funNomeSolucionador":null,"solNumArquivos":0},{"solCodigo":2219,"solDataSolicitacao":"2013-05-13T13:56:17","solDataPrevista":"2013-05-14T13:56:17","solPrioridade":3,"solDescricao":"asd","solStatus":"SP","proDescricao":"Connector","funNomeSolucionador":null,"solNumArquivos":0}], false),directEvents:{datachanged:{fn:function(store){var params=arguments;Ext.net.DirectEvent.confirmRequest({formProxyArg:"Form1",control:this,action:'DataChanged'});},delay:20}}}),id:"GridPanel1",renderTo:"GridPanel1_Container",autoHeight:true,title:"Solicitações",autoExpandColumn:"Descricao",sm:this.ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00=new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({proxyId:"",singleSelect:true}),selectionMemory:false,cm:this.ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01=new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({proxyId:"",defaultSortable:true,columns:[{dataIndex:"solCodigo",header:"Código",width:40},{dataIndex:"solDescricao",header:"Descrição",id:"Descricao",renderer:function(value){return Ext.util.Format.ellipsis(value,50);},commands:[{command:"Comando"}],isCellCommand:true,prepareCommand:prepareCellCommand},{dataIndex:"solDataSolicitacao",header:"Solicitado em",xtype:"datecolumn",format:"d/m/Y"},{dataIndex:"solDataPrevista",header:"Data prevista",xtype:"datecolumn",format:"d/m/Y"},{dataIndex:"proDescricao",header:"Projeto",id:"Projeto"},{dataIndex:"solStatus",header:"Situação",renderer:situacaoRender},{dataIndex:"solPrioridade",header:"Prioridade",renderer:prioridadeRender}]}),directEvents:{dblclick:{fn:function(e){var params=arguments;Ext.net.DirectEvent.confirmRequest({formProxyArg:"Form1",extraParams:{Values:Ext.encode(GridPanel1.getRowsValues({selectedOnly:true}))},eventMask:{showMask:true},before:function(el, type, action, extraParams){if(GridPanel1.getSelectionModel().getSelected() == undefined) return false; },control:this,action:'DblClick'});},delay:20}}});new Ext.Window({id:"wndChromeWarning",hidden:true,renderTo:Ext.get("Form1"),height:220,width:400,closable:false,buttons:[{id:"ctl03",xtype:"button",text:"Fechar aviso",listeners:{click:{fn:function(el,e){wndChromeWarning.hide()}}}}],header:false,padding:25,contentEl:"wndChromeWarning_Content",modal:true});});Ext.net.ResourceMgr.init({id:"ctl00$ResourceManager1",BLANK_IMAGE_URL:"/extjs/resources/images/gray/s-gif/ext.axd",aspForm:"Form1"});
```

Comment: Do you have an event handler declared for `GridPanel1_DblClick`?  If so can you post it?

Comment: I edited my question with the event you requested.

Comment: This one is a bit tricky, but I suspect that when you are going back to page 'A', the program is trying to locate a handler for a `DataChanged` event.  Total shot in the dark... maybe try adding said event to the `DirectEvents` element?

Comment: I did that, I put the event in the aspx and in the code-behind with no code at all. That stops the error, but that is a dirty workaround. But if there is no solution available, I'll stick with your solution.

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't suspect it as a "Clean" workaround - But since I have no clue why (or where) that event is being called, it was the only thing that came to mind

Comment: If there is no other answer to this question, please post it as an answer so I can mark as a solution and upvote you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky, but I suspect that when you are going back to page 'A', the program is trying to locate a handler for a `DataChanged` event. Total shot in the dark... maybe try adding said event to the `DirectEvents` element.

**Note**: 
I am posting this as an answer at the OP's request.  It was orginally in the comments.

Comment: I'll mark this as answer by tomorrow if there is no other answer. Upvoted because it is a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can guess that you add (somewhere?) DataChanged direct event handler in the code behind and don't readd that handler during next requests

That exception occurs if resource manager detects that a request is direct event request and the widget has no attached handlers for the event

Can you post generated javascript code for the problem page?

Comment: There is nothing named DataChanged in the entire solution. I'll add it tomorrow, not at work right now.

Comment: Ok, just edited with your request. There is a place where it is calling the DataChanged but I'm not declaring it anywhere.

Comment: Well, i see datachanged direct event in the generated script but direct event cannot be added by itself. Do you able to reproduce the issue in simple application with one page only? Also you can set breakpoint in the getter of DataChanged property of StoreDirectEvents class to see where the handler is set

Comment: You mean in the javascript or create the event manually and debug from there? And if the event is being added, it is something ext.net does because there is nothing with the name of DataChanged or anything related to that component in my entire solution.

Comment: I meant set breakpoint in Ext.Net code (getter of DataChanged property of StoreDirectEvents class)

Comment: Ext.Net doesn't set direct event handlers, there is no such logic in Ext.Net

Comment: Going through the Watch on `Store1.DirectEvents.DataChanged` there is no reference there. But it is weird because if I click in a link or input the url, I get no error. But if I press the left arrow of the browser, like returning to previous page, I get that error. On the first run, the generated JS code isn't there. That is why I find it weird.

Comment: Can you send me simple test application? I will investigate the issue (vladsch at mail.ru)